# fb:login-button size="icon" not work?

Tags: facebook, button, authentication, size

I'm trying to use the favicon option on the fb:login-button but it doesn't seem to work.

Anyone else got this to work?

Answer (score 2):

Known facebook bug

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/221835237886909?browse=search_4ef1a7976ee347107669468